# CakePHP customize flash message

Tags: cakephp, customization, message

Normally, the `$this->Session->setFlash(__('My message.'));`

Will output:

```
<div id="flashMessage" class="message">
    My message.
</div>
```

How can I change that, so it'll output:

```
<p class="notification>
    My message.
</p>
```

instead?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you look at the source code you will see that the second parameter of the SessionComponent method is the name of an element:

```
function setFlash($message, $element = 'default', $params = array(), $key = 'flash')
```

You can create a file in views/elements (or Views/Elements for Cake2) called for instance 'flash_notification.ctp'

with the following content:

```
<p class="notification">
  <?php echo $message; ?>
</p>
```

and use

```
$this->Session->setFlash(__('My message.'), 'flash_notification');
```

Comment: There's a typo in your answer btw, caused me a few minutes of hassle when I copied / pasted it! The `<p class="notification">` is missing the closing `"`. It's also possible to specify the element in the layout, like `<?php echo $this->Session->flash('flash', array('element' => 'flash_notification')); ?>`. In my case, doing that in default.ctp sets it across my whole application.

Answer (score 3):

According to [cakephp flash message](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/sessions.html#creating-notification-messages) no need to handle id and class in your view. You can set id and class when you setFlash as easy way.

```
$this->Session->setFlash(__('My message.'), 'default', array('id' => 'flashMessage', 'class' => 'message'), 'message');

$this->Session->setFlash(__('My message.'), 'default', array('class' => 'notification'), 'notification');
```

In your view.

```
echo $this->Session->flash('message');
echo $this->Session->flash('notification');
```

Thats it.

Comment: Great man! Even the manual wasn't so clear to me as your example! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

in app/element create .ctp file (example : flash.ctp)

```
<div class="alert alert-<?= (isset($alert)? $alert : 'info' ) ?>">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
<center>    <?= (isset($message)? $message : 'Something went wrong' ) ?></center>
</div>
```

and use

```
$this->Session->setFlash($message,'flash',array('alert'=>'info'));
```

define class,type in your css file to customize your Flash Message 
I hope this will help

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The button dismiss isn't working properly for me. Any tips?

Comment: You need to add js script for close action

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the current answers are a good approach to flash messages in general.

The entire application should simply have `$this->setFlash('my message');`and the parent view or layout should decide how to render it (even if it is by using an element).

The following code should be in the layout, perhaps in the `<head>` section.

```
<?php
        $flashMessage = $this->Session->flash();
        if ( $flashMessage !== false) {
            echo $this->element('my_custom_flash_element', array(
                'message' => $flashMessage
            ));
        }
?>
```

The layout captures it, and passes the flash message as a variable to the element 'my_custom_flash_element'.

Inside the element you can have all fancy rendering with css, and even cool stuff like toastr.js (which I personally love!)

Example: (my_custom_flash_element.ctp)

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
         <?php echo "toastr.warning('" . $message . "');"; ?>
    });
</script>
```

Also check out this wonderful concept on [transient flash messages](http://www.dereuromark.de/2014/04/21/cakephp-flash-messages-2-0/) by @dereuromark

Answer (score 0):

I found this workaround, using jquery.

I have this code in controller `if($var1 == null) { $this->Flash->error(__('Error message')); }`

In the /app/View/Layouts/default.ctp I put this code

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    if($('#flashMessage').length) // Check if flashMessage exists
    {
       var message = $('#flashMessage').html(); // Copy text
       // if I send html tags in the flash message,I use this code to print html
       message = message.replace(/&lt;/g, '<'); 
       message = message.replace(/&gt;/g, '>');

        if( $('#flashMessage').hasClass("error") ) // Check if it has the error class
        {
            // Create a bootstrap alert warning and set the message
            $('#flashMessage').html("<div class='alert alert-warning' style='width:50%'>"+message+"</div>");
        }

        if( $('#flashMessage').hasClass("success") ) // Check if it has the sucess class
        {
            // Create a bootstrap alert sucess and set the message
            $('#flashMessage').html("<div class='alert alert-success' style='width:50%'>"+message+"</div>");
        }           
    }
});
```