# detect if core flash messages in cakephp is an error or success message

Tags: cakephp

I have copied the SesionHelper from the core into myapp/View/Helper so I can alter the div structure around the message outputted.

My problem is that I cant seem to detect if the message is an error or success message from the default cakephp message. I know I can set a flash message in my controller and add an attribute. But there doesn't seem to be any extra data that I can see from the core messages.

Example if the data is saved to the database i wish to show the message as green. Or if the data could not be saved then as red message.

```
public function flash($key = 'flash', $attrs = array()) {
    $out = false;

    if (CakeSession::check('Message.' . $key)) {
        $flash = CakeSession::read('Message.' . $key);
        $message = $flash['message'];
        unset($flash['message']);

        if (!empty($attrs)) {
            $flash = array_merge($flash, $attrs);
        }

        if ($flash['element'] === 'default') {
            $class = 'message';
            if (!empty($flash['params']['class'])) {
                $class = $flash['params']['class'];
            }
            $out = '<div id="' . $key . 'Message" class="' . $class . '">' . $message . '</div>';
        } elseif (!$flash['element']) {
            $out = $message;
        } else {
            $options = array();
            if (isset($flash['params']['plugin'])) {
                $options['plugin'] = $flash['params']['plugin'];
            }
            $tmpVars = $flash['params'];
            $tmpVars['message'] = $message;
            $out = $this->_View->element($flash['element'], $tmpVars, $options);
        }
        CakeSession::delete('Message.' . $key);
    }
    return $out;
}
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused? Why would you alter the SessionHelper to change div outputs when you can do it with [Elements](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/sessions.html#creating-notification-messages) ([example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7990503/cakephp-customize-flash-message))? What is that solution not providing for you that you need to alter a Helper?

Comment: cakephp has it's own built in messages such as when you save something to the database it echo's 'The member has been saved', who can I tell this is a success message? If I set the message myself I could use setFlash('message', 'sucess')

Answer (score 4):

What you are doing is reinventing the wheel as far as CakePHP is concerned.

You can specify an element as the second argument when you set a flash message in your controller method:

```
$this->Session->setFlash('Your record has been saved', 'flash_success');
```

Then in elements create an element Element/flash_success.ctp like this:

```
<div class="alert-success"><?php echo $message;?></div>
```

And finally in your view:

```
<?php echo $this->Session->flash()?>
```

Here is the section that deals with this in detail from the official documentation:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/sessions.html#creating-notification-messages

Comment: Yes I am able to do this when I set the message. But what about cakephp own messages like where I save to the database. If you have a rule set in the model such only allow numbers. When you save from a form with alpha characters, the save will fail and cakephp sets a flash message as 'Cannot save data'. How do I know this is an error message. As opposed to when the data is saved I get the message 'The member has been saved'. Sorry if I am not clear, that the code you have is for when I set the message. My problem is when cakephp sets the message? Thanks for your help.

Comment: OK, I think you mean validation rules. If you are setting a message on each rule you can access individual messages with $this->validationErrors[Model][field]. To check if there are any validation errors you can check for the presence of  $this->validationErrors[Model];